# Invalid Binary issue in flutter IOS build

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

So, yesterday I build an app for ios, archive it and upload it to AppStore connect through xcode, everything seemed good but after few moments I received an email from apple saying:

Dear Developer,

We identified one or more issues with a recent delivery for your app, "APP-NAME" 1.0.1 (2). Please correct the following issues, then upload again.

ITMS-90755: Invalid Binary - The following binaries in your app contains prohibited instructions: /Volumes/data01/app_data/awf/SWImportWorker-mr47p00ce-swpr0068.cse.apple.com-300252/ff03-SoftwareImportWorker-MR_.0/NYH74E2GDJSTMWPVXUPB4IZWH4/umuagyjihbsjsrpn/wspvjpsuvltmmknh/Payload/Runner.app/Frameworks/App.framework/App. Remove the instructions from the binaries, rebuild and resubmit.

Best regards,

The App Store Team

I tried again with flutter clean and also increased the IOS deployment target but it didn't help.

My device's Flutter info:

Flutter (Channel stable, 2.5.0, on macOS 11.5.2 20G95 darwin-x64, locale
en-PK)
• Flutter version 2.5.0 at /Users/niteshkongreja/Development/flutter
• Upstream repository https://github.com/niteshcongreja321/flutter.git
• Framework revision 4cc385b4b8 (10 days ago), 2021-09-07 23:01:49 -0700
• Engine revision f0826da7ef
• Dart version 2.14.0

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
• Android SDK at /Users/niteshkongreja/Library/Android/sdk
• Platform android-31, build-tools 31.0.0
• ANDROID_HOME = /Users/niteshkongreja/Library/Android/sdk
• Java binary at: /Applications/Android
Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7281165)
• All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
• Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
• Xcode 12.5.1, Build version 12E507
• CocoaPods version 1.10.1

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
• Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
• Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
• Flutter plugin can be installed from:
 https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
• Dart plugin can be installed from:
 https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7281165)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.60.1)
• VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
• Flutter extension version 3.26.0

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
• macOS (desktop) • macos  • darwin-x64     • macOS 11.5.2 20G95 darwin-x64
• Chrome (web)    • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 93.0.4577.82

• No issues found!

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do was revoke my certificate, delete the mobileprovision file, then recreate both.

I also changed over to Air SDK 3.7.0.1530 and included the Default-568h@2x.png for the iphone splash screen, and well... it seems to have worked.